# Interpretation of logistic regression coefficients when there are multiple levels

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, interpretation

Suppose that the model had the following output:

```
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)              0.07       0.33      0.21   0.829     
x0_low                   0.44       0.22      1.96   0.049   * 
x1_m                    -0.51       0.25     -1.98   0.047   * 
x1_l                    -0.05       0.22     -0.24   0.809     
x2_no                    0.51       0.26      1.94   0.051   .
```

where

- `x0` has levels `hi, low`
- `x1` has levels `s, m, l`
- `x2` has levels `yes, no`

I'm wondering what an interpretation for the coefficient `x1_m` would be.

It seems as though it could be:

*`x1_m` reduces the `log(odds)` by roughly 40% having adjusted for `x0` and `x2`*

But what I'm a bit confused about is whether this is actually what it's saying,
because `x1_m` is simply a level within the factor `x1`, so does that change its
meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x0`, `x1` and `x2` are factors. So, so called 'reference levels' are chosen for them (by default these wolud be their first levels: `hi`, `s` and `yes` respectively).

All the coefficients of the model can be interpreted as a difference between 'modelled' and 'reference' level.

So, in you case, `x1=m` reduces the `log(odds)` by roughly 0.51, as comapred to `x1=s` and  having adjusted for `x0` and `x2`.

Comment: I didn't realise that the interpretation of a beta coefficient for log odds could be considered as a percentage, for some reason i thought that was just when the exponential was taken, thanks

Comment: You're right. Answer edited